# Powers of a prime as one more than the square of an integer...

Tags: number-theory

Given a fixed prime $p$, are there finitely many positive integers $k$ such that $p^k = n^2 +1$ for some $n$?

Comment: Certainly true if the $abc$-conjecture is true.

Comment: I think "any" would be more appropriate than "some".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more general equation $n^2+1 = y^k$ for *any* positive integers $n$ and $y$ was proven to have no solutions for $k\geq 3$ by Lebesgue in 1850.  Obviously, there are no solutions for $k=2$ since the smallest difference between positive perfect squares is 3.

See [Bugeaud](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FCOM%2FCOM142_01%2FS0010437X05001739a.pdf&code=210923257f916a830e528452fc6608c7) for complete details (including generalization to $n^2+D = y^k$).

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you.